# How to join different models with primary key in Django?

Tags: django

I am very new on Django. I wanna make patient storage system but i'm stuck.
These things must be in project.
1-) In my project i want to add hundreds of patients and also some new patients can add their own infos via register.
2-) Every patients will answer more then 300 questions, so i wanna split the model for good user experience.

Here is the my problem.
I split the main models, and then i add some basic information from hastaekle.html and then when i looked the admin panel. I see this selection page on the image at below. How can it be automatically.

[image]

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.




class HastaProfil(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hasta_ad = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    hasta_soyad = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    hasta_dogum_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=155)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hasta_ad + ' ' + self.hasta_soyad

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('hasta-aliskanlik')  


class HastaAliskanlik(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sigara = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    alkol = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    uyusturucu = models.CharField(max_length=155)          

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sigara

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('hasta-listele')      
    

class Hasta(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hastaprofil = models.ForeignKey(HastaProfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    hastaaliskanlik = models.ForeignKey(HastaAliskanlik, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import  HastaAliskanlik, HastaProfil, Hasta
from django import forms

class HastaProfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = HastaProfil
       
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
           
            'hasta_ad' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'} ),
            'hasta_soyad' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'hasta_dogum_yeri' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tıklayarak Seçiniz'}),
           


        
        }  


class HastaAliskanlikForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = HastaAliskanlik
       
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
           
            'sigara' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'} ),
            'alkol' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'uyusturucu' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tıklayarak Seçiniz'}),
           


        
        }          



class HastaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Hasta
       
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
           
            'hastaprofil' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'} ),
            'hastaaliskanlik' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            #'uyusturucu' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tıklayarak Seçiniz'}),
           


        
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import HastaProfilForm, HastaAliskanlikForm, HastaForm

from .models import HastaProfil, HastaAliskanlik, Hasta

# Create your views here.

class HastaProfil(CreateView):
    model = HastaProfil
    form_class = HastaProfilForm
    template_name = 'hastaekle.html'

class HastaAliskanlik(CreateView):
    model = HastaAliskanlik
    form_class = HastaAliskanlikForm
    template_name = 'hasta_aliskanlik.html'

 


def HastaListele(request):
    tum_hasta = Hasta.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'hasta_listele.html', {'tum_hasta': tum_hasta})    



def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

hastaekle.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hasta Ekle </title>
</head>


<body>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Anasayfa </a><br>
    <a href="{% url 'hasta-listele' %}"> Hasta Listele </a>

<h1>Hasta Ekle </h1>

<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}    
<h3>Hasta Profil Ekle:</h3> 
Hasta Ad: <input type="text" name="hasta_ad"/><br/>
Hasta Soyad: <input type="text" name="hasta_soyad"/><br/>
Hasta Doğum Yeri: <br/>
<textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="hasta_dogum_yeri">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>



</html>
```

hasta_aliskanlik.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Alışkanlıklarınız </title>
</head>


<body>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Anasayfa </a><br>
    <a href="{% url 'hasta-listele' %}"> Hasta Listele </a>

<h1>Hasta Ekle </h1>

<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}    
<h3>Alışkanlıklarınız:</h3> 
Sigara: <input type="text" name="sigara"/><br/>
Alkol: <input type="text" name="alkol"/><br/>
Uyuşturucu: <br/>
<textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="uyusturucu">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>



</html>
```

hasta_listele.html

```
<h1>Hastalar</h1>

<a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Anasayfa </a><br>
    <a href="{% url 'hasta-ekle' %}"> Hasta Ekle </a>

<ul>
{% for post in tum_hasta %}

<li><a href="#">{{ post.hastaprofil.hasta_ad }} {{ post.hastaprofil.hasta_soyad }}</a> 

    
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do it in this way because the problem what if multi users post data in same time in **HastaProfil** and **HastaAliskanlik** and for example one user post on **HastaProfil** and another one on **HastaAliskanlik**, how you will now this information for any user?

you should add on those model special field like **user** or link between those model, after that you can use access data in easy way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

```
class HastaAliskanlik(models.Model):
    hasta_profil = models.OneToOneField(
        HastaProfil,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    sigara = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    ...
```